# Constructor with Calendar - New Object

Tags: java, calendar

My code:

```
public MyCode (Calendar example1, String example2){    
    this.example1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    this.example2 = example2;    
}
```

How I do create objects with parameters?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? How to create an object of `MyCode`?

Comment: Have you at least looked at the documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Comment: What you want to achieve? What parameters are you talking about?

Comment: You can [answer or delete your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Comment: <pre>MyObject nameObject = new (???, "My text");<code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example of a class with a constructor with only getMethods

```
public class MyCode 
{
  private GregorianCalendar example1 = null;
  private String example2 = null;

  public MyCode(Calendar example1 , String example2) 
  {
    this.example1 = example1
    this.example2 = example2;    
  }

  public GregorianCalendar getExample1 ()
  {
   return example1;
  } 

  public String getExample2 ()
  {
   return example2;
  } 
}
```

I would suggest reading the tutorial in the comment and the following 
http://howtoprogramwithjava.com/object-oriented-programming-java-tutorial/

use of the class is as follows

```
MyCode myfirstObject = new MyCode(new GregorianCalendar(),"My First Object");
```